# In Zombie Kittens why would you resurrect another character?

Tags: exploding-kittens, zombie-kittens

I was going through [this site](https://www.explodingkittens.com/pages/how-to-play-zombie-kittens) but I am not understanding why one would "resurrect" another player?

Wouldn't it be more advantageous to let them stay dead?

Answer (score 2):

Because they don't have a choice if the want to save themselves as the rules say they must bring a dead player back if there are any.

> Whenever a player chooses to play a Zombie Kitten to save themselves
> from exploding, they must bring a Dead player back into the game (if
> there are any).
>
> If they choose to bring you back into the game, they will put their
> Zombie Kitten in the Discard Pile and then they will take the
> Exploding Kitten that killed them AND the Exploding Kitten in front of
> you and put both of them separately back into the Draw Pile anywhere
> they’d like in secret (the two Exploding Kittens can be put in two
> different locations). You are now a Living player and must take your
> turns as normal.
>
> You can still play a Zombie Kitten if there are no Dead players. If
> you play a Zombie Kitten and there is more than one Dead player, you
> must choose one of the Dead players to bring back into the game.

Comment: OK so it's only to counter the exploding kitten after the fact.